# i am not able to display native ad admob ad in between adapter list on my recycler view

Tags: java, android, admob, native-ads, google-native-ads

i want to display native ads in between adpaterlist in recycler view .The native ad is not showing but the adapterlist aswell as progress bar works fine

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NotNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        if (i == 1) {

            return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_template_adapter_list, viewGroup, false));//show list of items

        }
        if (i != 2) {
            return new LoadingHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress_view, viewGroup, false));//shows progressbar
        }
        return new AdHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_view, viewGroup, false));//this statement never called for loading native ad
    }
 public Object getItem(int i) {
        return this.posterDatas.get(i);
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = this.posterDatas;
        if (arrayList == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
        if (this.isLoaderVisible) {
            if (i == this.posterDatas.size() - 1) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (this.posterDatas.get(i) instanceof String) {
                return 2;
            }
            return 1;
        } else if (this.posterDatas.get(i) instanceof String) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

`return new AdHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_view, viewGroup, false));`
this line is never executed thats why ad is not loading because i==2 condition never occurrs

i want to show both native ad and adapterlist items in parallel. Native ad should show between adapterlist items as given in the image.Because the value of i==2 doesnt occur am not able to execute the return statement for adloader

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF5mq.jpg)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/626Ew.jpg)

[full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11NePHYsfEyJBMB9EVtH1Pk7cvuV67BdI/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have followed the steps in this documentation : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7187428?hl=en

hope this helps ... good luck ❤️.